# How to Update/Insert(upsert) a large table chunk wise using pandas

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There is large table which needs to be upserted(update/insert) using python pandas library with a new dataframe(which contains latest data).

I could able to do that considering the entire table.But since the table is heavy and will grow heavier in future I am looking for upsert options chunkwise on the table.

Below code is the current code to upsert the table.data_frame2 is the new data frame(contains latest data).

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://username:password@hostname/schema")
con = engine.connect()
sql1 = "select * from table1"
df1 = pd.read_sql(sql1, con)
#(upsert code starts),can below code be converted into chunkwise upsert
#data_frame2 is the data frame with latest data/new data.
df_final = pd.concat([df1, data_frame2[~data_frame2.index.isin(df1.index)]])
df_final.update(data_frame2)
#upsert code ends
#writing data chunkwise
df_final.to_sql(con=con,name='table1',if_exists='replace',chunksize=100000)
```

I have researched online but could not able to find a way where we can do chunkwise upsert(update/insert) on a table with new data in pandas dataframe.Please suggest how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more of a database task than python task. If the data grows how your local memory will be able to manage that? So the heavy part should be done in the server of my SQL so that you do not need to download the data and do any update. So to do that the things you need:

- Create a temp/staging (Ex. table2) table in the database with the df1 columns and constrain
- Insert `df1` to the temp table2 in the database
- create a db object and cursor using mysql connector

  ```
  import pymysql

  conn = pymysql.connect(host='', port='', user='', passwd='', db='')

  cur = conn.cursor()
  sql_update_string = "update ..." # join table1 and table2 and update the common ids in table1
  ```
- Execute the update task using python cursor and close the cursor

  ```
  cur.execute(sql_update_string)
  cur.close()
  ```